# How can I add condition in pipeline in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, pipeline

My data was 450K (DNA methylation data). And the results below are from regional analysis. It contains three columns: the chromosome number, start position, and end position:

```
region <- structure(list(chr = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 21L, 22L), start = c(95663987L, 80531500L, 154334651L, 24536765L, 187476837L, 16179633L, 2751822L, 63461803L, 133562246L, 29521568L, 49813031L, 24772270L, 128593922L, 30038286L, 6649733L, 65913660L, 51184152L, 6414602L, 5543801L, 22370347L, 24890330L), end = c(95664360L, 80531899L, 154334652L, 24537302L, 187476838L, 16180267L, 2752602L, 63461931L, 133562777L, 29521715L, 49813487L, 24772351L, 128594418L, 30038311L, 6649995L, 65913661L, 51184887L, 6415253L, 5543946L, 22370759L, 24891142L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(4L, 12L, 15L, 14L, 20L,8L, 10L, 18L, 1L, 16L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 21L, 9L, 17L, 13L, 7L, 19L, 11L, 3L))
```

The distribution in my region is:

```
table(region$chr)
```

The first chromosome is chr2, chich contains four regions here.

Now I have another probe file, which contains probes with their chromosomes and positions. What I want to do is to extract the probes that are lociated in my target regions. Here is probe file:

```
probe <- structure(list(chr = c(6L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 17L, 16L, 13L, 3L, 17L, 20L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 8L, 6L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 18L, 2L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 22L, 15L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 16L, 9L, 6L, 19L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 19L, 14L, 17L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), pos = c(159064992L, 114367005L, 28835671L, 200003800L, 42692969L, 73780663L, 65236094L, 114057675L, 23713773L, 56326765L, 44142512L, 103668081L, 111806472L, 4437077L, 8871457L, 143771621L, 29993498L, 696801L, 79623625L, 69385761L, 30685686L, 76190435L, 14031049L, 3732002L, 32853151L, 146233339L, 71757240L, 131844944L, 128424176L, 89749142L, 27693242L, 57138252L, 43123399L, 57407842L, 29067224L, 53191387L, 30921630L, 107971593L, 125133314L, 109915400L, 46668882L, 14720858L, 67804654L, 23500367L, 170398571L, 150241781L, 85843232L, 15106710L, 33758223L, 44350860L, 83726483L, 76814245L, 3789435L, 55013663L, 166846008L, 150289488L, 3187835L, 169684620L, 1340602L, 35297146L, 61569177L, 122954569L, 71276472L, 9563665L, 9952926L, 81040735L, 15392793L, 55183957L, 27228679L, 139334396L, 44090748L, 3979938L, 125425262L, 10687769L, 503198L, 55191642L, 19735701L, 184244831L, 10738664L, 17446073L, 140739501L, 49384054L, 56618196L, 71324066L, 27221689L, 8041137L, 149033953L, 169224907L, 3933591L, 76450658L, 46152449L, 93250590L, 1025591L, 37024552L, 1360335L, 156277860L, 157098423L, 85980756L, 2575755L, 142138643L, 80531898L, 80531597L, 80531656L, 95664233L, 95664359L, 95664243L, 80531645L, 80531599L, 80531500L, 80531842L, 95663987L, 80531751L, 154334651L, 80531633L)), row.names = c("cg13598865", "cg02666265", "cg16662787", "cg10513702", "cg10970751", "cg08536977", "cg09084496", "cg08794696", "cg18648917", "cg20272962", "cg03013946", "cg07028608", "cg10361696", "cg06618629", "cg25307778", "cg00888489", "cg21092551", "cg07760369", "cg04317962", "cg08627125", "cg18512512", "cg13901901", "cg13524180", "cg18761756", "cg23633993", "cg07013148", "cg06190759", "cg14070745", "cg11552868", "cg26635451", "cg03201274", "cg25063425", "cg04482817", "cg05082527", "cg24850711", "cg25194273", "cg18964706", "cg01485362", "cg14154487", "cg22511293", "cg01431908", "cg20219035", "cg18855836", "cg06743703", "cg07489447", "cg16269716", "cg12737876", "cg00001245", "cg24871046", "cg07065008", "cg02104456", "cg13466901", "cg17880816", "cg23352067", "cg26870903", "cg12489846", "cg04144333", "cg02399652", "cg24269412", "cg03146993", "cg17307051", "cg20129534", "cg07968224", "cg07814910", "cg02192555", "cg07629951", "cg13322252", "cg18456312", "cg02871891", "cg07874283", "cg26371345", "cg07663404", "cg07036530", "cg17677988", "cg16619777", "cg25182165", "cg20686479", "cg04184793", "cg22513691", "cg17183414", "cg04246144", "cg05383531", "cg25245322", "cg02244933", "cg05516617", "cg11111132", "cg07760722", "cg05357093", "cg08248181", "cg00780666", "cg26932693", "cg14681854", "cg23853026", "cg08044454", "cg22317004", "cg05907764", "cg05482973", "cg03128635", "cg01968492", "cg03460049", "cg00465284", "cg00549910", "cg02856109", "cg03445516", "cg06816651", "cg09409539", "cg09482777", "cg11231249", "cg12078605", "cg21621248", "cg24871414", "cg26355577", "cg26649384", "cg27629977"), class = "data.frame")
```

Below was what I tried: extracted probes chromosome by chromosome, and region by region. Let's take the chr2 for example.

```
chr2 %>% probe %>% subset(chr==2) %>% subset(pos >= 95663987 & pos <= 95664360 | pos >= 80531500 & pos <= 80531899 | pos >= 154334651 & pos <= 154334652)
```

It worked well and showed 14 probes that are located in these four regions. However, my real region file have many more regions whitin each chromosome. It will be time comsuming to put all the "start" and "end" number in the code. So I want to have a easier code to extract the probes, at least chromosome by chromosome.

Below was what I tried:

```
chr2.df <- probe %>% subset(chr==2) %>% subset(pos >= region$start & pos <= region$end)
```

It showed no regions...

Can anyone help me with it - how to extract the probes not by using the detail "start" and "end" number in the region file?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Correction: the chr2 dataframe contains three regions not four.

Comment: There is a problem in the code `chr2 %>% probe` it should be `chr2=probe`. While the condition for `subset` has to have some numerical value for `pos`. If you want to extract the probes it is sufficient to filter with your `chr==2` condition.

Comment: Is your goal to identify probes that are in each of the (chromosome-specific) regions?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to identify probes that lie in each chromosomal region, then I think that this code will suffice:

```
library(magrittr)
pdf <- tibble::as_tibble(probe ) %>% dplyr::mutate(probe = rownames(probe))

region %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  dplyr::left_join(pdf, by = "chr") %>%
  dplyr::filter(pos < end, pos > start)
```

I first load the package `magrittr`, which lets me use the "pipe" function, `%>%`. I then create a tibble (a data frame) with probe as a (new) column. This reflects my preference to not use rownames with data frames.

I then convert `region` to a tibble (a type of data frame) before piping it to the `left_join` function from `dplyr` package. This function "merges" or "joins" the two data frames by common values of "chr". Since there are repeated values of "chr" in both region and pdf, we get multiple lines with, for example, "chr" value of 2.

Lastly, I use the function `filter` from `dplyr` to choose only those rows that have a `pos` value between `start` and `end`.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Hi, Fred, thanks so much for your help. It works pretty well.

Comment: Is there something else that you're trying to do? I'm not sure that I understand your goals.